# предотвращение mixed content при загрузке KML с HTTP ссылками

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

При экспорте карты с точками в kml из конструктора Яндекс-карт KML файл содержит HTTP ссылки на иконки типа 
    http://api-maps.yandex.ru/i/0.4/micro/pmbls.png
При загрузке такого KML через ymaps.geoXml.load Chrome выдает ошибку mixed content даже если заменить ссылки на иконки после загрузки:

```
ymaps.geoXml.load('https://****/test.kml').then(function (res) {
res.search('geometry.type == "Point"').each(function (item) {
    item.options.set('iconImageHref', item.options.get('iconImageHref').replace(/^http:/,'https:'));
}).addTo(clusterer);
```

})

При этом все иконки отображаются, но на каждый тип иконок выдается по 1 предупреждению о mixed content.

В качестве workaround можно руками конвертировать KML, но интересует полноценное решение.

Comment: Напишите в техподдержку Яндекса, они исправят это.

Comment: В техподдержке признали проблему. Но сроки решения не обозначили.
Изначально полагал, что сам где-то налажал.

Comment: Я думаю все имеют право на промах)